NetMod Error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"
I am using an application called NetMod, and I am using an SSH configuration. However, the problem is that when I press start, I cannot connect, and the log shows the message:

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
access permissions.

I have tried reinstalling the driver for the Wi-Fi adapter, but the result was unsuccessful. Then I tried restarting HNS (Host Network Service), but the problem is that I could not find HNS in service.msc, and I am using Windows 11.
I have tried following the solution from the answer here, but honestly, I don't understand how to perform the procedure.

Host Network Service) is svchost and it's impossible for it not to be running on your system. Have you tried a different VPN client other than NetMod?

Provide the output of netstat -o which will require running it in an elevated command prompt.

@Ramhound But I have searched for it in services, svchost, or hostnetwork service, and it really doesn't exist, even when I type net stop hns, it says not available.
